# Did Modernism believe urban life was bad?

Tags: modern

I'm not entirely sure whether this is the correct site for my question by here it is:

My English teacher recently mentioned that the [Modernist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modernism) movement believed that urban landscapes were essentially "bad" due to causing individuals to feel alienated.

I've read various articles online and haven't found anything which confirms this.

My question is: was there ever this belief in Modernism that urban life was "bad"?

Thanks in advance (if my question isn't appropriate for this site, it'd be much appreciated if you could redirect me somewhere)

Comment: " The movement reflected a desire for the creation of new forms of art, religion, philosophy, and social organization which reflected the newly emerging industrial world, including features such as urbanization, new technologies, and war." [Wikipedia:Modernism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modernism)  Doesn't sound like a rejection of urban life to me.  Could your teacher have been using irony?

Comment: From the Wiki article on Modernism you linked, maybe Edmund Hopper? On his painting Nighthawks it says: "The urban street is empty outside the diner, and inside none of the three patrons is apparently looking or talking to the others but instead is lost in their own thoughts. This portrayal of modern urban life as empty or lonely is a common theme throughout Hopper's work."

Comment: @History Maybe your teacher was talking about [romanticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanticism) rather than modernism?